How to do sparse * dense element-wise matrix multiplication with different dimension efficiently with pytorch?

What I want

I want to do element-wise matrix multiplication of two matrix:

sparse matrix A with shape (3,4,5)

dense matrix B with shape (100,10,4,5)


I am expecting to do element-wise matrix multiplication on the last 2 dimensions of these matrix
So the resulting matrix C=A*B have shape (100,10,3,4,5)
I want to do this more efficiently. What can I do?

What I currently do

I checked the docment of the Pytorch.sparse, which indicates to use the operator * to do element-wise matrix multiplication.
However, this operator only support 2-dimension matrix. I have to iterate over the first dimension of matrix A and the first two dimensions of matrix B to do 2d*2d matrix multiplication to get the right results, which is not efficient.
